# Shared a google drive folder with google service account, but service account can't see it

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Writing an application that will crawl an uploads directory for packaged zip files uploaded by users, and recreate the in-zip directory structure in a Google for Work shared google drive folder.

Problem: The shared folder is not accessible or visible to the service account created in the For Work domain. Code is in C#. I hope I'm just missing something stupid.

Details: Logged in as the domain admin account. Go into the google api console, enable api, create a service account, grant access to that service account's email. Via API and service account, shared folder is not found in the list of File objects, nor can I upload to it by ID.

The following snippet is called using the in-url folder ID of the shared folder. The folder that is shared to the service account doesn't show up in the list of stuff returned.

```
// get starting point

    string masterParent = "xxxxx"; // pulled from URL after sharing folder
    File masterParentFolder = GetGAPIFileById( service, masterParent, false );
```

Example Snippet:

```
static File GetGAPIFileById( gapi.DriveService service, string id, bool folderOnly ) {
    if( null == id ) id = "-1";
    File rtn = null;

    var lreq = service.Files.List();
    lreq.MaxResults = 10000;
    if( folderOnly ) {
        lreq.Q = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false";
    } else {
        lreq.Q = "trashed=false";
    }
    var lres = lreq.Execute();

    foreach( File f in lres.Items ) {
        Console.WriteLine( "Item: " + f.Title + " // " + f.Id );
        if( f.Id.Trim().ToLower() == id.Trim().ToLower() ) {
            rtn = f;
            break;
        }
    }

    return rtn;
}
```

Comment: I should add that doing this exact same procedure in my personal gmail account and sharing a folder from my personal drive to a service account I create there works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Well, as it turns out, it seems the issue was caused by, or exacerbated by changing the share-out-of-domain setting, and not waiting for full propagation before sharing the folder, and creating the service account. After deleting everything and redoing the exact same steps, roughly 5 days after the initial attempt, things are working properly. When Google says "this may take up to 24 hours" and it seems to work just fine within a few minutes, go ahead and leave the stuff alone and come back to it a day or two later.

:: shrug :: Thanks, all.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisH ... having the exact same issue